# Page not defined issue when running Playwright Test

Tags: automation, playwright

I am new to playwright. When calling methods in different class using object instance, throwing error as "Page not defined".

Code as below:
Page.test.ts

```
 import { expect } from "@playwright/test";
    import { Page } from "playwright-core";
    
    export class petStoreLoginPage {
        
        private page: Page;
            constructor (page : Page) {
            this.page = page
        }
        
        //Locators
    
        eleSignIn = async () => await this.page.$("text=Sign In")
    
        eleUserNm = async () => await this.page.$("input[name='username']")
    
        elePwd    = async () => await this.page.$("input[name='password']")    
    
        eleLogin  = async () => await this.page.$("input[value='Login']") 
    
        eleWelcomeScreen = async () => await this.page.waitForSelector("div[id='WelcomeContent']")
    
        eleSignOut = async () => await this.page.$("text=Sign Out")
    }
    
    actions.test.ts
    import { expect, Page } from '@playwright/test'
    import {petStoreLoginPage} from '../Pages/pt.page'
    
    declare const page : Page
    let userInOut : petStoreLoginPage = new petStoreLoginPage(page)
    
    export class userInOutAction  {
       
        public async clickSignIn() {
            
            const ele = await userInOut.eleSignIn()
            if (ele != null)    
                await ele.click()
            else throw new Error("No element found")
        }
    
        public async clickSignOut() {
            const ele = await userInOut.eleSignOut()
            if (ele != null)
                await ele.click()
            else throw new Error("No element found")
        }
    
        public async enterUserNm(userNm : string) {
            const ele = await userInOut.eleUserNm()
            if (ele != null)
                await ele.fill(userNm)
            else throw new Error("No element found")
        }
    
        public async enterPwd(pwd : string) {
            const ele = await userInOut.elePwd()
            if (ele != null)
                await ele.fill(pwd)
            else throw new Error("No element found")
        }
    
        public async clickLogin() {
            const ele = await userInOut.eleLogin()
            if (ele != null)
                await ele.click()
            else throw new Error("No element found")
        }
    
        public async verifyHomePage() {
            const ele = await userInOut.eleWelcomeScreen()
            if (ele != null)
                expect(await ele.innerText()).toBe("Welcome cgtdemo!")
             else throw new Error("Welcome page not landed!!!")
        }
    
        public async verifyLoginLogoutPage() {
            const ele = await userInOut.eleSignIn()
            if (ele != null)
                expect(await ele.innerText()).toBe("Sign In")
            else throw new Error("Welcome page not landed!!!")
        }
    
    }
```

test1.test.ts

```
import {  test } from '@playwright/test';
import Environment from '../Environment/environment';
import {userInOutAction} from '../Actions/pt.actions'



test("TC01 - Login and Logout Petstore Application", async ({page}) => {

    let login : userInOutAction =  new userInOutAction()

    await test.step("Step 1 - Go to PetStore Application and Click SignIn", async () => {
        await page.goto(Environment.test);
        await login.clickSignIn();
        await login.verifyLoginLogoutPage();
    })
    await test.step("Step 2 - Enter username and password", async () => {
        await login.enterUserNm("cgtdemo");
        await login.enterPwd("cgtdemo");
    })
    
    await test.step("Step 3 - userInOutAction to PetStore Application", async () => {
        await login.clickLogin()
        await login.verifyHomePage()
      })
    await test.step("Step 4 - Signout the PetStore Application", async () => {
        await login.clickSignOut()
        await login.verifyLoginLogoutPage()
      })
  })   
  test.afterAll(async({page}) => 
{
        await page.close()
  })
```

When giving npx playwright test , getting ReferenceError: page is not defined. Able to know it is because of the page is calling properly but I dont see any issue in code and not throwing any error.

Comment: You should pass to `userInOutAction` the page you get in the test.